# Fitting an established site into a CI framework

Tags: php, object-oriented, mvc, frameworks, codeigniter

I manage a rather large, feature full nightmare of a site which has no end of feature creep settings/options/etc.

Up to now its been coded in a procedural/functional way and would like to move to an OO,MVC setup. I'm quite new to it all but have done alot of research and feel that CodeIgniter is a code choice of framework to use to help quicken the transfer. Before looking at a framework, I started constructing a list of objects to create classes out of:

- photos
- users
- forum topics
- forums
- blogs
- blog posts
- comments

The trouble I have now, is I do understand where these generic/universal objects fall into the CI MVC setup. What is the best way to organise this kind of stuff? These classes can generally be used on multiple models/views/controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"These classes can generally used on multiple models/views/controllers". From a MVC perspective there is no problem of a model being used in several controllers and views.

So you are left with the model, but as far as I see, there should simply be one model class for each of those objects, since they relate to one database table each. Then they may interact with each other, which partially may be handled by the controller or by the models themselves (depending a bit on use case, preferably by the models).

Comment: In other words, "these classes" basically *are* the models (though not without some refactoring to get non-model code where it belongs).